# javascript - not working "for" loop

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a Snake Game, but I have an issue

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx');

var y = [240, 230, 220];
var x = [240, 240, 240];

var xSpeed = 0;
var ySpeed = 0;

function load() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (p = 0; p < x.length; p++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x[p], y[p], 10, 10);
    }
}

function keyDown() {
    var key = event.keyCode; /*getting keyCode of pressed key*/
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"; /*color of rectangle*/
    switch (key) {
        case 39: //RIGHT
            xSpeed = 10;
            ySpeed = 0;
            break;
        case 37: //LEFT
            xSpeed = -10;
            ySpeed = 0;
            break;
        case 38: //UP
            xSpeed = 0;
            ySpeed = -10;
            break;
        case 40: //DOWN
            xSpeed = 0;
            ySpeed = 10;
            break;
    }
}

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (x[0] >= 490) {
        xSpeed = 0;
    } else if (y[0] >= 490) {
        ySpeed = 0;
    }

    console.clear();

    y[0] += ySpeed;
    x[0] += xSpeed;

    for (i = x.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        y[i] = y[i - 1];
        x[i] = x[i - 1];
        console.log(i);
    }


    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);
        //console.log("y= " + y[i]);
        //console.log("x= " + x[i]);
    }

    //console.log(xSpeed);
    //console.log(ySpeed);
}

setInterval(update, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>The Snake Game</title>
</head>
<style>
    #ctx {
        position: absolute;
        /*it can be fixed too*/
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        /*this to solve "the content will not be cut when the window is smaller than the content":*/
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>

<body onkeydown="keyDown()" onload="load()">
    <center><canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas></center>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

If you run the above code you'll find that the iterator in the for loop is increasing in value instead of decreasing. I think the mistake is somewhere in the loop but I can't see it.

```
for (i = x.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[i] = y[i - 1];
    x[i] = x[i - 1];
    console.log(i);
}
```

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: it's worth noting that you should declare the variable `i` as if you don't it will become global and running a subsequent function with `i` could end up with unforeseen consequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
for (i = x.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[i] = y[i - 1];
    x[i] = x[i - 1];
    console.log(i);
}
```

you are iterating starting iteration at element `x.length` which is the the top index in the `array +1`.  Then you are iterating down to  0.  So the first time you do `x[i] = x[i-1]` it adds an element to your array.

This should fix it:

```
for (i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[i] = y[i - 1];
    x[i] = x[i - 1];
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = x.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[i] = y[i - 1];
    x[i] = x[i - 1];
    console.log(i);
}
```

1. When `i=0` you try to grab index `-1`
2. The first `i` is set to the length of the array which is 3 but the indexes are `0-2` so you are out of bounds **so it will add a new value on each run** since it will place it as new value at the end of the array

The array indexes are: (array indexes are 0 based)

```
[0] = ...
[1] = ...
[2] = ...
```

But the length is `3`

Answer (score 1):

you do not have place to y or x at x.length

```
for (i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[i] = y[i - 1];
    x[i] = x[i - 1];
    console.log(i);
}
```